# js: how to make a loop that adds 20 diff things to an object

Tags: javascript

I get how to do this with arrays
I just can't figure it out when doing it with objects

```
array.push("blah");
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: It is a little unclear what you want. What kind of properties would the object in mind have? "Add 20 diff things to an object" can mean lots of things. An object could e.g. have an array and a function that adds to that array.

Comment: The plain object equivalent of `array.push(value)` is `obj[key] = value`, noting that you need both a value and a key, and depending on your needs you might need to test if a property with that key already exists. (Whereas pushing to an array you only need a value because it automatically gets the next index at the end of the array.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. I think i know what you're going on about though.

So say we wanted to add a new KEY to an object every loop we could do something like this:

```
var objectName = {};
for (var i=0;i<20;i++){
    objectName['key_'+i] = 'value here'; 
}
```

This would generate keys inside the objectName object. The above code would generate `{key_1: 'value here', key_2: 'value here', etc...}`

As you can see with the above snippet, you'll easily be able to add arrays and objects within the objectName variable.